# No audio from Panasonic Toughbook FZ-55 MK2

Tags: audio, alsa

Installed successfully Elementary OS on Panasonic Toughbook FZ 55. Managed to get nearly all hardware configured and working, including bluetooth which I had troubles with on other distributions.

I'm having an issue with getting audio from speakers however. If I plug in headphones, I get audio. I tried several things:

- installed "pavucontrol" for Pulse Audio
- tried settings (saw 3 HDMI audio outputs, unsure where to set the order or priorities)
- tried "alsamixer" from command line to select audio cards
- tried setting audio output card when using VLC

Linux audio is tricky and I feel that I am missing something very simple yet can't figure it out.